# I Need Bigger Font in Python IDLE

Tags: python, fonts, python-idle

Context for why I'm asking:

I am currently teaching a course on Python. I am using IDLE to show basic syntax in the shell. My screen is projected onto a large screen. The maximum font size in IDLE's preferences is 22. This is decently sized, but when projected, the students in the back have trouble seeing it. I don't want to use a different IDE or text editor, because I want the class to easily follow along, and write and execute along with my examples.

What I am asking:

I need larger font in IDLE. The max font size is 22. Is there a way to manipulate this in my local installation? Or does anyone know of an extension for IDLE that fixes this issue?

Comment: Could you just zoom in on the command line interface in which you're running IDLE? At least on a mac, this is easy to do with `command +`.

Comment: Do you need to use IDLE when teaching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The font size selection had ended with 22 for at least 15 years.  It is set by this statement in `idlelib.ConfigDialog.py` (or `configdialog` in 3.6).  It is about line 1000.

```
    self.optMenuFontSize.SetMenu(('7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13',
                                  '14', '16', '18', '20', '22'), fontSize )
```

Extend the sequence as you wish, such as to

```
    self.optMenuFontSize.SetMenu(('7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13',
                                  '14', '16', '18', '20', '22',
                                  '25', '30', '35', '40'), fontSize )
```

At present, you will have to re-patch every time you update.

This [tracker issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue17642) is about changing font size within a window with key or mousewheel.  The use case of projecting is mentioned.  Now that I know this is a real, not hypothetical issue, I will make this issue a higher priority.  If you tell me what size you need, I might extend the fixed list something like the above.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll have a better idea of what exact size will be appropriate once I return to the classroom this week, but I'm thinking size 30~35 will work great.

Comment: I am definitely want to add choices to 2.7.13 and 3.6.0b1 (about Sept 10).  That will probably be it for 2.7 and key or wheel changes will likely be only for 3.6, and maybe 3.5.  3.5.3 will follow later.  I am now thinking of extending 20, 22, with 25, 29, 34, 40 for increments of 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6.  But I will wait for your tests.

Comment: Hello again Terry, those changes sound perfect. I ran IDLE on OS X displayed on a project at size 34 font. It seemed like a great size. The students in the back could read it quite clearly. Thanks again for your help. I am excited to see the changes made permanent once you get around to it!

Comment: and by 'project' I mean 'projector'*

Comment: The expanded list will be in 3.6.0b1 and 2.7.13 and 3.5.3 if I don't forget to backport later.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

```
File >> Setting >> Editor >> Font
```

then you can modify the font size (I don't see any limitation).